# Getting differences between old and new versions of ArcSDE database?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

Is there a tool or a process that can reveal changes made to the schema of an ArcSDE database when comparing two versions of the same database hosted on different servers?

I have an old database that has been running a site, and a newer version, and I'd like to be able to get a heads up about what has changed in terms of schema and contents.

Comment: Different SDE versions within the same db *always* have matching schema. Schema modifications to any version always affect all versions - even older ones.

Comment: @Ragi Yaser Burhum - The different versions are hosted on separate servers. I've edited it to clarify that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT:** This looks like the best option from [NASA in 2010](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16977).

---

archiving is now availble in 10.0

[image: archiving]

Also track user changes is coming :) [oops.](http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/supportcenter/archive/2011/09/28/arcgis-beta-community-arcgis-10-1-beta.aspx)

You might also look for "[the differ](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14742)" script. It is a bit old but might give some direction.
and old [editor tracking](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15694)

Answer (score -1):

The schema comparison between Old SDE and New SDE through  the GeoData Sentry third party product which work on top of ArcGIS.